# Curl-style redirection in Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, redirect, curl, cookies

I'm trying to write some code to redirect a web page visitor to a specific URL but hide the redirect path also ensuring that all cookies from the redirect path are stored Ok on the client PC.

This PHP Curl code emulates what I'm trying to do -

```
$affurl = 'http://testurl.com';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $affurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie111.txt');// set where cookies will be stored
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie111.txt');// from where it will get cookies

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$url = curl_getinfo ($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
curl_close($ch);
```

Apart from the fact that it is doing all this redirecting on the server, so the cookies & IP referrer are all based on the server.

I want to do exactly the same thing but from the client browser i.e. so that the referring IP address, cookies etc are all set & stored on the client.

I read that this may be possible in Ajax, can this be done?

Or is there some other way of hiding redirect paths whilst retaining the referring IP & all cookies?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that client side.
Which seems quite great if you ask me, otherwise any website could take you anywhere, steal your cookies, and have you doing whatever they want with your own connection.

Comment: Fair enough, and point taken :) But on the wider question, is there a way to redirect a visitor and hide the redirect path from a scraper?

Comment: Maybe using a captcha before redirecting.

Comment: Unfortunately can't use a Captcha, the redirect needs to go through every time